# Android SDK manager does not open

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I have Android SDK installed on Debian.
However, when i go to sdk/tools/bin and I try to open sdkmanager using terminal, it says

```
bash: sdkmanager: command not found.
```

The file file sdkmanager is there, so why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

How are you entering the command to start the sdkmanager. You should be entering `./sdkmanager`, unless the 'sdk/tools/bin' folder or the sdkmanager command is on your PATH ([How to add a directory to your path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path))

Comment: No worries, glad I could help